# swagger-node: using swagger "project edit with" $ref (multiple files)

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-node-express, swagger-node

I'm checking out swagger node. This seems to be something basic so it's hard for me to believe it's a bug.

I create the sample swagger hello world project as indicated on the swagger-node git page using `swagger project create hello-world`.

I use a `$ref` to an external file with relative path but it's unable to open the file. Using the console I can see that it attempts a request but there's a 404 error. It seems that the swagger editor can only access the swagger.yaml file but nothing else.

as a test I copied the referenced hello.yaml file to every folder of the project and still getting `Reference could not be resolved: hello.yaml`

swagger.yaml

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "0.0.1"
  title: Hello World App
# during dev, should point to your local machine
host: localhost:10010
# basePath prefixes all resource paths 
basePath: /
# 
schemes:
  # tip: remove http to make production-grade
  - http
  - https
# format of bodies a client can send (Content-Type)
consumes:
  - application/json
# format of the responses to the client (Accepts)
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /hello:
    $ref: hello.yaml
  /swagger:
    x-swagger-pipe: swagger_raw
# complex objects have schema definitions
definitions:
  HelloWorldResponse:
    required:
      - message
    properties:
      message:
        type: string
  ErrorResponse:
    required:
      - message
    properties:
      message:
        type: string
```

hello.yaml

```
# binds a127 app logic to a route
x-swagger-router-controller: hello_world
get:
  description: Returns 'Hello' to the caller
  # used as the method name of the controller
  operationId: hello
  parameters:
    - name: name
      in: query
      description: The name of the person to whom to say hello
      required: false
      type: string
  responses:
    "200":
      description: Success
      schema:
        # a pointer to a definition
        $ref: "#/definitions/HelloWorldResponse"
    # responses may fall through to errors
    default:
      description: Error
      schema:
        $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have meet the same issue, and I have found that it's a swagger-editor bug.
Please find the description at [Known Issues](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/README.md#known-issues).
It will give the info `Relative path support for external files is not implemented.`